# My test.js file isn't outputting anything when i do "node test.js" or anything else

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to test a simple program with node:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function doubleInput(arrayItem) {
  return arrayItem * 2;
}
```

But for some reason nothing outputs when i do node.js in the terminal. Am i missing something? I do have node installed (v20.3.0).

My output should be:
`2, 4, 6, 8, 10`

But sadly, nothing shows up

I simply have just a test.js file that has an array with values and then a function that multiplies by two and returns that result. I tried adding a .npmignore file, a package lock and package.json adding in i still have the same results. Also in terminal i do

```
node test.js
```

Comment: Why do you expect any output? You never _use_ either `myArray` or `doubleInput`, and certainly don't `console.log` anything.

Comment: Your code defines a function and sets a variable.  Nothing currently in it would produce any output. (You never actually _call_ the function, and even if you did he function would simply return the value to the caller, not output it in any way you'd see by running it on the command line.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method and `join`

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function doubleInput(array) {
    return array.map(x => 2 * x);
};

let res = doubleInput(myArray);

console.log(res.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code outputs nothing, because you're not calling your function, and you're not printing anything.

I would also suggest using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in your case. You can use it like this:

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

result = myArray.map(x => x * 2)

console.log(result);
```

Outputs

> [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]

Comment: also can you explain what .map does in your own terms?

Answer (score 0):

You actually didn't **call** your function `doubleInput`, that's why you didn't get any output,
Even though you *invoke* it, you gonna get `NaN` since `return arrayItem * 2`; is like  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] * 2` which always gives `NaN`;

The right way is looping over each value, Doubling it and storing it in an array, and finally returning that variable.

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function doubleInput(arrayItems) {
  let returnedArrayOfItems = [];
  for(let i=0; i<=arrayItems.length-1; i++){
    let arrayItem = arrayItems[i];
    returnedArrayOfItems.push(arrayItem*2);
  }
  return returnedArrayOfItems;
}
console.log(doubleInput(myArray))
```

Comment: Thank you for a more detailed example.